# Separate different Strings from text

Tags: android, string, arraylist, readline

I want to read a txt file that contains a lot of different chunks of text separated by a string. In xcode this is pretty easy and i just use.

```
self.Array = [text componentsSeparatedByString: @"NEWSTRING"];
```

I don't seem to get this to work in android though, I can read in the whole text and put it into an array but it doesn't get separated so its just one long text.

I am using this code

```
        AssetManager mngr;
    String line = null;
    boolean skillcheck = false;
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(0);
    String[] bb = null;
    tester = new ArrayList <String>();
    try {   
    mngr = getAssets();
    InputStream is = mngr.open("mytext.txt");
    InputStreamReader sir = new InputStreamReader(is);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(sir);
    while((line=br.readLine()) != null) {


        sb.append(line);
        sb.append("\n");



    }


    tester.add(sb);



    br.close();

    } catch (IOException e1) {


    }
```

Any good ways to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [String.split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method

```
String[] result = text.split("sometext");
```

For your acknowledgement

> `String.split` returns the array of strings computed by splitting this
>   string around matches of the given regular expression

Answer (score 2):

You should use `StringTokenizer`.

```
StringTokenizer sTok=new StringTokenizer(stringVariable, "newString");
while(sTok.hasMoreTokens())
System.out.println(sTok.nextToken());
```

`stringVariable` is the file contents and `newString` is the delimiter string.

**EDIT**

The second parameter of the `StringTokenizer`'s constructor is the `delimiter`. It can be a new line `\n` or comma `,` or whatever you want.